# How can I use Enums on my Razor page in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I declared an enum:

```
public enum HeightTypes{    Tall,    Short}
```

Now I want to use it on my razor page like this:

```
@if (Model.Meta.Height == HeightTypes.Tall)
```

But there's a problem as I get an error. Is there some way I can tell the razor page about my enum?

Comment: Please be specific about the error. Exact message copied verbatim from the compiler / IDE, preferably.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have an error in your enum declaration (remove the trailing `;`):

```
public enum HeightTypes { Short = 0, Tall = 1 }
```

then the following test should work:

```
@if (Model.Meta.Height == HeightTypes.Tall)
{

}
```

you just have to make sure that your view is strongly typed and that you have brought into scope the namespace in which the Height enum is defined:

```
@using SomeAppName.Models
@model SomeViewModel
```

or reference the enum like this:

```
@if (Model.Meta.Height == SomeAppName.Models.HeightTypes.Tall)
{

}
```

But to avoid doing this in all your razor views that require using this enum, it is easier to declare it in the `<namespaces>` section in the `~/Views/web.config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="SomeAppName.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Sorry I just corrected that. I was getting mixed up. The problem I have is really I think with MVC because my razor view doesn't know about the namespace that the enum is in.

Comment: @Richard, yes, you could add a `@using` at the beginning of your Razor view.

Answer (score 15):

Just do give a start-to-finish example:

C# CS Page

```
namespace MyProject.Enums
{
    public enum CurveBasis
    {
        Aggregates,
        Premium
    }
}
```

Razor View

```
@using MyProject.Enums

<select id="dlCurveBasis">
    <option value="@CurveBasis.Aggregates">Aggregates</option>
    <option value="@CurveBasis.Premium">Premium</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specific about the exception, so I'm *guessing* this is a namespace issue. Add

```
@using The.Namespace.Of.Your.Enum;
```

at the top. You can also specify namespaces to add automatically in `/Views/web.config` if you are going to use that namespace a lot:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages ...>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web" />
            ...
            <add namespace="The.Namespace.Of.Your.Enum" />
```