# How to get Enum value in Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I used `datatables` and I want to get `Enum` value for a specified int `variable`.

```
var client = $('td', row).eq(1).text().trim();
```

**client** is a number data type.

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
var x=@Enum.GetName(typeof(Client),client);
```

> client does not exist in the current context

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot mix javascript and c# code like that (one runs on the client and one runs on your server)

Comment: you can't  mix js with razor.

Comment: How can i resolve the problem ?

Comment: You can only mix JS and C#/Razor in a server->client direction. That is, server-side values can be set *once* at the time the response is sent to the browser, *before* the browser sees it.

Comment: Actually, you can use Razor in your JS. You can't use JS in your Razor.

Comment: You could use ajax to post the value to the server and return the text value. Or you could pass a collection/dictionary or the enums `int` and `name` values to the view and convert it to a javascript array and search that array for the corresponding value.

Comment: Are you using jQuery dataTable?

Comment: @mmushtaq, yes.

Comment: Then you could have a hidden `td` in which you could pass `Enum Name` against each `client value`.

Comment: I get a int number from database and i have to get the enum string which have this number value.

Comment: Yes and pass this value name in DataTable data and [hide this column](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html) and retrieve this hidden column value whenever you need it.

Comment: I have aprox. 10 those enums and I send very large data and i think that's not a good idea.

Comment: Then as StephenMuecke suggested you have to call ajax or you could use js arrays.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please post your idea in order to accept answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, Bit busy just now - wont be for an hour or so

Comment: Please check the following link, it might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640983/how-can-i-use-enums-on-my-razor-page-in-mvc3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Enum.GetName(typeof(Client), client);` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. `client` is a javascript variable which does not exist at that point (its not in scope).

On option would be to pass a collection of the `enum` names and values to the client, and assign it to a javascript array so it can be searched.

For example, create a class to represent the names and values

```
public class EnumValues
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller

```
IEnumerable<EnumValues> clientValues = 
    from Client c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Client))
    select new EnumValues
    {
        ID = (int)c,
        Name = c.ToString()
    };
```

and pass it to the view in a view model property, or using `ViewBag`

```
ViewBag.ClientValues = clientValues;
```

In the view, assign it to a javascript array, and create a function to return the name for a corresponding value

```
var clients = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ClientValues));

function getClientName(value)
{
    for(var x = 0; x < clients.length; x++) {
        if (clients[i].ID == value) {
            return clients[i].Name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and use it as

```
var client = $('td', row).eq(1).text().trim();
var clientName = getClientName(client);
```